# How to relate these two sentences

Tags: conjunctions, sentence-structure

I wrote:

> To eliminate embedded advertisements or navigation links (e.g. links to the related articles) from the main article, the link density and text density features were used **so that / in which / where** a link density above 33% or a text density less than 10.5% was used as the indicator of boilerplate.

Which phrase can relate the the explanation of the experiment to its configuration setup? I think *where* is the correct choice? How about *so that* or other alternatives?

Comment: I've down-voted because your grammatical question has nothing to do with the settings of an experiment. The sentence is run-on. Break it into two sentences, or use a participle phrase, "...were used, a link density above 33% or a text density below 10.5% *indicating* boilerplate".

Comment: @TRomano I really don't know how to find a title for this question. I modified it to a more specific title.

Comment: OK. I've removed the downvote.

Comment: The thought is murky. It is not clear how the determination that an article is boilerplate will eliminate embedded advertisements and navigation links from it.

Comment: @tromano the article is not boilerplate but the embedded advertisement within it, which are distinguished by a higher link density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are listing the specific conditions for a result

> so that
>   such that
>   where

are appropriate

> ...features were used **so that** a link density above 33%...
>   ...features were used **such that** a link density above 33%...
>   ...features were used **where** a link density above 33%...